# Increment with recursion

Tags: java, recursion, increment

I want to make this increment with recursion:

`000
001
002
100
101
102
200
201
202
300
301
302`

I know where to start and to end with
`String a = 000;`
`String b = 302;`
respectively.
I'm trying by this code:

```
private static void extendToMax(String l, String h)
{
    StringBuffer sb;
    for(int i=2; i>=0; i--)
    {
        sb = new StringBuffer(l);   
        if(charToDigit(l.charAt(i)) < charToDigit(h.charAt(i))) {           
            sb.replace(i, i+1, inc(sb.charAt(i)));  
            extendToMax(sb.toString(),h);
        }   
        if(checkElementary(sb.toString()))
        {
            if(array.indexOf(sb.toString())<0)
                array.add(sb.toString());
        }   
    }
}
```

but the output is `001 002 102 202 302 201 202`. The number `202` is not supposed to be repeated.

Comment: It increment's like this now:

001
002
102
202
302
201
**202** <- Already printed

Comment: Why are you using recursion?  An iterative solution makes far more sense for this problem.

Comment: @JoeC Like how? It looks a bit like binary but idk I want only to achieve in a best way the results

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the sequence... Why do you want 303 to be printed if your "range" is 000 to 302?

Comment: @Stefan That's wrong thanks, it should stop at 302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to solve this, using recursion.

The first `loop` method is just to get things started (it just fills in an empty `prefix`). The second `loop` method does recursion for each of the positions of the `start` and `stop` strings. When it has passed the last position, it prints the result (which is then contained in the `prefix`).

```
private void loop(String start, String stop) {
    loop("", start, stop);
}

// Assume start.length==stop.length, and that start<stop at each position
private void loop(String prefix, String start, String stop) {
    if (start.length() > 0) {
        for (int c = start.charAt(0); c <= stop.charAt(0); c++) {
            loop(prefix + (char) c, start.substring(1), stop.substring(1));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    }
}
```

This works for strings of any length, for example from `00103` to `12115`.

Comment: Lovely solution!

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit biased here of course, but I think this should be the Accepted answer :)
I don't think that extendToMax solution really works.

Comment: Imo, they are already sorted. What result do you get, and what result would you like to get?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
static String l="000";
static String h="232";
static ArrayList<String> combinations = new ArrayList<String>();
static int stringLength= l.length();
for(int i=0; i<rulelength; i++)
{
    combinations.add((charToDigit(h.charAt(i)) - charToDigit(l.charAt(i))+1)+"");
}
int number = 1;
for(int i=0; i<combinations.size(); i++)
{
    number*=Integer.parseInt(combinations.get(i));
}
int change = Integer.parseInt(combinations.get(combinations.size()-1));
expand(l, h, change, number);

public static void expand(String l, String h, int change, int comb)
{ 
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(l);
    int pos = stringLength-1;
    int tmpPos = pos;
    for(int i=1; i<=comb; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        sb.replace(pos, pos+1, inc(sb.charAt(pos)));
        if((i % change)==0) {   
            for(int j=stringLength-1; j>0; j--)
            {
                if(charToDigit(sb.charAt(j)) >= (Integer.parseInt(combinations.get(j))-1)) 
                    tmpPos = j-1;                   
                else
                    break;
            }
            sb.replace(tmpPos, tmpPos+1, inc(sb.charAt(tmpPos)));
            for(int j=stringLength-1; j>tmpPos; j--)
            {
                sb.replace(j, j+1, l.charAt(j)+"");
            }
        }
    }
}
```